# Persisting custom enum values in ORMLite

Tags: enums, ormlite

I would like to persist the Enum  not as String and not as the ordinal but rather as the given number in the constuctor:

```
public enum EAdUnitType {
    NOTIFICATION(1), 
    BANNER(2);

    private int mId;

    public int getId() {
        return mId;
    }
}
```

I would like to persist the getId().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can add to the enum from id

```
public enum EAdUnitType {
   NOTIFICATION(1), 
   BANNER(2);

    private int mId;

    public int getId() {
       return mId;
    }

    public static EAdUnitType fromId(int id) {
      EAdUnitType [] types = EAdUnitType .values();
        for (EAdUnitType eType : types) {
            if (eType.mId == id) {
                return eType;
            }
        }
      return null;
    }
}
```

and save the numeric id into to the database

```
public class DbEntity {
   private int mEAdUnitTypeId;

   .....

   public void setEAdUnitType(EAdUnitType type) {
      mEAdUnitTypeId = type.getId();
   }

   public EAdUnitType getEAdUnitType() {
      return EAdUnitTypeId.fromId(mEAdUnitTypeId);
   }

   .........
}
```